# Symfony2 and jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I am developing an application using Symfony2 and Jquery as a JavaScript FW. I am using Twig for the templates. I render a template from the controller and after making a selection using the cursor in the template I would like the value of the selected tag to be returned to the controller when submitting using a submit button in the mentioned template.

I use the next Jquery function:

```
$("MatchedTag").click(function () 
 {
       $(this).toggleClass("highlight");

       var IdOfTag = this.id;  
       $.ajax({
          url: "{{ path('AcmeAcmeBundle_myaction') }}",
          type: "POST",
          data: { "tag_id" : idOfTag },
          success: function(data) {
             //(success) do something...
             //variable "data" contains data returned by the controller. 
          }
       });
});
```

I guess in the controller, in myaction I should use something like $_POST["tag_id"] or getrequest() , bindrequest() to get the value but I dont really know how. Could someone give me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to get this parameter by :

```
 $request->request->get('tag_id');
```

**Update**
 *simple action*

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController
{
   public function indexAction($name)
   {
     $myParam = $request->request->get('tag_id');
     // write your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Just that? And how i would write i want the parametet to be get when the template is submited? Could you please give me an example of how the controller action would look? @rayan.gigs? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @rayan.gigs! And the call to the template will be done afterwards inside the controller? How can i know the yemplate has been aubmited an so i can use te value in te argument?