# Ajax call to Controller and XML response Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2. Now I want to implement my previous practice for ajax call using Symfony2.

I want to make an ajax call to a server side code and get XML response and extract it. Here is what I do.

```
var data={
            type:'1'                           

        };

        jQuery.ajax({
                  url: 'server_script/check.php',  //load data 
                  global: false,
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  data: data,
                  async: false, 
                  success: load_data2
        });
```

In **flat php** file I can catch that and using

```
$type=$_POST['type'];
```

In **Symfony2** I'm making AJAX call by using

```
           jQuery.ajax({
                          url: '{{ path('create_label') }}',  //load data 
                          global: false,
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "xml",
                          data: data,
                          async: false, 
                          success: load_data2,
                          error: problem
                    });
```

And in Controller that comes from the create_label,I catch it using

```
$type->request->get('type');
```

I'm not sure yet though if it's really working. Got it from this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570853/symfony2-and-jquery-ajax)

Next in **flat PHP** I produce a XML response by

```
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
            echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
            echo "<Loadinglist>\n";
            echo "</Loadinglist>";
```

It gave me a response that I extract in `function load_data2(xmlindata)` method.

Now I'm not able to make any valid XML response in Symfony2. I tried few tricks but none of them are working. **I want to send a XML response from Controller , catch it and extract in with the `load_data2` method.** If you have time please provide an wiki type answer that how the xml response work is done.

(N.B. In **flat php** I could check the XML  response in console or firebug, will I be able to view the same in **Symfony2**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the POST parameter, it's better to be explicit and use `$request->request->get('type')`. This will only get the POST parameter 'type' and not the GET parameter 'type'.

Next, a controller always returns a `Response`. This class can be seen as a PHP port of the real HTTP response. So you can tweak it to return XML.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class YourController // ...
{
    function someAction(Request $request)
    {
        // ...

        $response = new Response(<<<EOX
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Loadinglist>
</Loadinglist>
EOX
        );
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
}
```